# how to read subprocess pipe without buffering

Tags: python, subprocess, pipe, buffer

How can i read pipe's buffer without waiting. Subprocess is executing Swift script. If it was a python script, there is a flag for python that makes pipe unbuffered (-u). Any other ways to solve this ?

```
sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(['swift', 'script2.swift'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
thr1 = threading.Thread(target=self.pipe_reader, args=[sub_proc.stdout]).start()
thr2 = threading.Thread(target=self.pipe_reader, args=[sub_proc.stderr]).start()


def pipe_reader(self, pipe):
    for line in iter(pipe.readline, b''):
        self.q.put((pipe, line))
    self.q.put((pipe, None))
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Changed line(added stdbuf -o0 as a argument)

```
sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(['swift', 'script2.swift'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
```

to

```
sub_proc = subprocess.Popen(['stdbuf', '-o0','swift', 'script2.swift'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

For further information about stdbuf:  https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html